# Override std::hash<std::string> to use Google's City Hash

Tags: c++, c++11, hash, stdhash

So, simple enough question as I'm having a brain dead moment.. How can I override/replace `std::hash<std::string>` to use Google's City Hash?

My current approach is to have a wrapper around `std::string` and then specialize `std::hash<>` for that. But this is painful as I have to implement virtually the same interface as `std::string` and I want to avoid this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't replace any existing specializations, i.e., you can't replace `std::hash<std::string>`. However, you *can* use a different hash function objects with the `std::unordered_*` containers, e.g.:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, T, my_hash> hash_map;
```